# To check if a given string start with A-Z in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I had an programming interview few days ago, I am required to write a piece of code in Perl with the functionality described in the title, after a while, I came up with the following solution:

```
sub startWithUppercaseLetter {
    return @_[0] =~ m/^[A-Z]/;
}
```

The interviewer seems unhappy with this solution, can anybody give a better one? thanks

Comment: Maybe he wanted lowercase, too, either by adding `a-z` to the character class, or via the `i` switch. I don't know Perl, but the regex seems solid (for uppercase).

Comment: Or perhaps it's *words* that start with a letter, implying the word boundary: `\b`...

Comment: I presume the interviewer's worry was with you accessing an array element with `@`. The first element of `@_` is `$_[0]`. Or you could use `shift`.

Comment: @aliteralmind could you be more specific by providing an example? thanks :)

Comment: @aliteralmind Do you mean the string could start with characters like +,* and so on? I tested the code with strings such as " ", "+A", which could start with a non-word character, it all return 0.

Comment: `\b`=word-boundary, `[A-Za-z]`=Any letter, uppercase or lowercase, `+`=one or more of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write

```
sub starts_with_capital {
  shift =~ /^[A-Z]/;
}
```

Your own solution doesn't survive `use warnings`, giving

```
Scalar value @_[0] better written as $_[0]
```

and it is bad practice to use upper case letters in local identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I would really think this is not a good use of the title since your regular expression will return empty  matches or matches (what do you want as a definition of the problem to solve).  The person could also imagine having type this function name over and over again to check if something has a Capital.

So many ways to do it in Perl.

```
return @_[0] if /^[A-Z]/;

return;
```

The m really is not needed as you only want the start of the string and any new lines etc, as you are concerned only if first character starts.  Your way, yes can have an empty match and works the same; make it readable for interviews or provide two examples : long hand as above and then short hand.

Comment: Why do you say *"your regular expression will return empty matches or matches"*?

Comment: Yes, I should be more specific, it will return a 1 for match or nothing for a match. I tested the code in the shell and this is the result, no match , returns blank , match returns 1.

Comment: @alexmac I tested it before, I think it will return 0 if not match.:D

Comment: I admire your answer though no need for the m, just for your interview try to be very clear even if you have to dumb it down for the interviewer; he may also think he has dumb staff members who would not be smart enough to read your answer.  Being able to maintain the code afterwards is key.